# Best way to limit WCF Service to specific User Accounts

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I will be hosting a basic HTTP WCF service using Window Service / Service Host.
I would like to limit the service to 2 specific window active directory users and these accounts will vary between PRD and DEV environments so they will be set in a config file.

I was wondering what is the best way to do this, I know normally if I was hosting the service using IIS then I could limit it in the Web.config:
http://www.rickgaribay.net/archive/2007/04/04/recipe-wcf-basichttpbinding-with-windows-authentication.aspx
However since i'm hosting using ServiceHost then I don't believe this is an option.

From what I read it seems possible to do this using PrincipalPermission Declarative attribute at the service class level:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms731200(v=vs.100).aspx
However I'm not too clear whether this will pass the window account of window service or the account which made the HTTP request. What I need is to pass the HTTP request account.
Also, with declartive attributes, is it possible to use a config file attribute rather than a hard coded one?

Any suggestions, if you need any more info then let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following article suitable for what I needed, basically it involved authorisation using a behavior:
http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-create-aspnet-windows.html

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Role-Based authorization. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx#id0070004